# Problema com envio via URL ( GET)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, url, get

Bom dia amigos, tenho esses botões aqui:

```
    <button class="btn-excluir" data-id="1">Primeiro</button>
    <button class="btn-excluir" data-id="2">Segundo</button>
    <button class="btn-excluir" data-id="3">Terceiro</button>
    <button class="btn-excluir" data-id="4">Quarto</button>
    <button class="btn-excluir" data-id="5">Quinto</button>
```

E esse simples script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

             var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-excluir');

             for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {

                  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {

                  var a = e.target.dataset.id;

                  ajax_envio('script.php?variavel=' + a);

                        }, false);

               }

               function ajax_envio(arquivo) {

                   var http = new XMLHttpRequest;

                   http.open('GET', arquivo, true);
                   http.send();


                }

                        </script>
```

O código do PHP, para pegar o valor da variável:

```
<?php $valor_da_variavel = $_GET['variavel']; 

      echo "Valor da variável: $valor_da_variavel";    ?>
```

O script basicamente pega o *data-id* do botão e envia esse valor para a variável *$valor_da_variavel*.

Porém, ai está o problema: a *URL* não quer se alterar, apesar de que quando aperto *F12* e vou na parte *NETWORK*, e dou clique um em algum botão, mostra, na coluna *Name*, o que deveria parecer na *URL*. Aparece basicamente isso:

**Name:** *script.php?variavel=2* (se eu clicar no segundo botão)

**Status:** *200 OK*

**Type:** *xhr*

**Initiator:** *script.php:72* (na linha onde há o ***http.send();***)

**Size:** *2.5Kb*

**Time:** *10ms*

E como estou usando $valor_da_variavel como parâmetro em uma função, ela está retornando nulo.

Gostaria de saber qual pode ser o problema. Quanto ao PHP. a mensagem de erro que tenho é:

Index indefinido: valor_da_variavel (Que é o $valor_da_variável);

Agradeço desde já!!

Comment: E esse `:` após o `echo`?

Comment: Opa, na hora de editar aqui devo ter colocado, mas em meu código está normal, sem o ":"

Comment: Então o problema deve ser na função do PHP. O Ajax está enviando o valor normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Fala meu caro! Tudo bem?

Fiz o teste do código na minha máquina e após incluir o script para carregar junto com a página "window.onload" ele funcionou normalmente. Enquanto a modificação da URL que aparece no navegador o Ajax ele não faz essa alteração uma vez que ele faz solicitações assíncronas por padrão.
Recomendo dar uma lida [nesse material](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/javascript/o_ajax_e_seu_funcionamento) sobre o funcionamento do ajax.

Para ver se o script php esta retornando a informação correta, inspecione a página e verifique no network (selecionando a solicitação) e na aba "Response". Igual na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vlw cara. Pois é o problema é na função mesmo, mas acabei conseguindo de uma outra forma, veja na resposta abaixo

Answer (score 0):

Quanto ao problema, acabei fazendo de uma forma mais simples e melhor (na verdade não sei se é melhor pois não sei praticamente a diferença):

Ao invés de `<button></button>`, eu usei um `<a></a>`, e coloquei `href"script.php?variavel=2"`, e deu certo.

Assim a variável pegou o valor normalmente e deu certo. Porém, apenas deu certo quando ficou fora da função, dentro de função parece que a captação da variável não funciona, não sei porque. Mas tirei da função mesmo, e ficou jóia.